# libACE and clang/clang++, undefined reference to `ACE_Atomic_Op<ACE_Thread_Mutex, long>

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, clang++, ace

I'm compiling an application using clang++ 3.8 , libACE 6.3.3 and including the -std=c++11

But i'm having issues with inclusion of ACE Atomic_OP

including such headers:

```
#include <ace/ACE.h>
#include <ace/Thread.h>
#include <ace/TSS_T.h>
#include <ace/Atomic_Op.h>
```

i've

> ../game/libgame.a(WorldSocketMgr.cpp.o): In function
>   `ACE_Atomic_Op<ACE_Thread_Mutex, long>::operator--()':
>   /usr/include/ace/Atomic_Op.inl:72: undefined reference to`
>   ACE_Atomic_Op::decrement_fn_'
>   ../game/libgame.a(WorldSocketMgr.cpp.o): In function
>   `ACE_Atomic_Op<ACE_Thread_Mutex, long>::operator++()':
>   /usr/include/ace/Atomic_Op.inl:50: undefined reference to`
>   ACE_Atomic_Op::increment_fn_'
>   ../game/libgame.a(WorldSession.cpp.o): In function
>   `ACE_Atomic_Op<ACE_Thread_Mutex, long>::operator=(long)':
>   /usr/include/ace/Atomic_Op.inl:166: undefined reference to`
>   ACE_Atomic_Op::exchange_fn_'
>   ../game/libgame.a(WorldSession.cpp.o): In function
>   `ACE_Atomic_Op<ACE_Thread_Mutex, long>::operator-=(long)':
>   /usr/include/ace/Atomic_Op.inl:114: undefined reference to`
>   ACE_Atomic_Op::exchange_add_fn_' clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

How can i solve it?

UPDATE:

i've changed

```
ACE_Atomic_Op<ACE_Thread_Mutex, time_t> m_timeOutTime;
```

in

```
ACE_Atomic_Op<ACE_Thread_Mutex, int> m_timeOutTime;
```

and

```
ACE_Atomic_Op<ACE_Thread_Mutex, long> m_refs;
```

in

```
ACE_Atomic_Op<ACE_Thread_Mutex, int> m_refs;
```

it now compiles, but i'm not sure it's a safe solution.

Comment: Do you have the same inline settings when you compile ACE and when you compile your application, check the INLINE defines that we pass when invoking the compiler

Comment: I'm using libace-6.0.3 from ubuntu repositories, i'm not compiling them

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not able to compile with clang using external ACE from OS. So i'm trying now to include it in my project:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014042/pic-error-compiling-ace-with-clang

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen could you explain me better what do you mean please?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

This was caused by a bug in ACE prior to version 6.4.3. It is now fixed.

---

### Original Answer:

A little late response, but I hope it may help anyone who finds this post in the future.

It looks like ACE has a bug (or just did not update their code). Unfortunately, the only solution for now is to hack ACE's files.

You need to find edit either config-linux.h or config-macosx-snowleopard.h - based on what you use. Then you find this chunk of oode and delete it:

```
# ifdef __clang__
#  undef ACE_HAS_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS
# endif
```

Comment: The necessary changes are now part of ACE and will be part ACE 6.4.3 or newer

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen I have updated the answer accordingly, Thank you.